# How to update only a column in phoenix?

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I have an existing HBase table, and I'm using phoenix-sqlline.

I added 2 new columns(let's call them A and B) to the existing table, and they have NULL values as of now.

I want to update these 2 columns to a value (let's say A to 1.0 and B to 0.1) without any condition.

How can I do it using phoenix sqlline?

Note:
There's this one way to read the data from HBase tables in Spark dataframe, and manipulate the data, and re-write it back, but I want to avoid that way.

I tried UPSERT specifying only one column, but didn't seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [UPSERT SELECT](https://phoenix.apache.org/language/index.html#upsert_select)?

Example:

```
UPSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE(PRIMARY_KEY, A, B)
SELECT PRIMARY_KEY, 1.0, 0.1 FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE <condition>;
```

It would be helpful if you could provide the upsert command you used.